# Scons Environment() strange behavior

Tags: environment, scons

I am playing around with scons build . When i use the following to import my system path :

```
env = Environment(ENV={'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
```

assuming i am using gcc compiler , the path is set in C:\cygwin\bin

The above work perfectly , however if I try to split them :

```
ENV={'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']}
env=Environment(ENV)
```

The below error show that the path is not added correctly ...

```
g++: error: /Fomaino.obj: No such file or director
g++: error: /c: No such file or directory
g++: error: /I.: No such file or directory
```

It does not work ?  I have even try the following :

```
 env=Environment()
 env['PATH']= os.environ['PATH']
```

same error

```
g++: error: /Fomaino.obj: No such file or director
g++: error: /c: No such file or directory
g++: error: /I.: No such file or directory
```

I try to use the following in SCONS user guide

```
env['ENV']['PATH'] = 'C:/cygwin/bin'
```

also fails.

I already have an working approach , but i am curious why the other two approach fails which i think in term of logic they are the same... or I am wrong...

Comment: What version of Python? (windows or cygwin, and 2.7, 3.5+?)   Are you trying to use Cygwin's gcc, or mingw non-cygwin?

Comment: Hi , i am using Python 2.7 , I am using Cygwin's gcc

Comment: Look that I have found the problem , it seem that the ENV has to be set for Environment function to knows : 
ENV={'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']}
, env = Environment(ENV=ENV)

Answer (score 0):

Any additional SCons Environment variables that you want to be set in the Environment should be passed as keyword arguments to the Environment constructor:

```
Environment(VAR=VALUE)
```

From the [SCons Users Guide](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#app-functions):

> `Environment([key=value, ...]) , env.Environment([key=value, ...])`
>
> Return a new construction environment initialized with the specified
>   `key=value` pairs.

Comment: Not strictly true.  env['MY_VAR']='my value' is also a way to do that. Note that these values don't propagate to the shell tools are run in, but are used to evaluate build strings in actions. To set values to propagate to the shell used to run the commands you'll want to set env['ENV']['MY_SHELL_VAR']='My shell value'

Comment: @bdbaddog I suppose my wording is too strict. I specifically mean to answer why the asker's code does not work. Thanks.